# UnicodeDecodeError when tokenizing Thai language text in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tokenize, python-unicode, thai

I am trying to tokenize thai language text using [deepcut](https://github.com/rkcosmos/deepcut) in Python and I am getting UnicodeDecodeError.

This is what I have tried

```
import deepcut

thai = 'ตัดคำได้ดีมาก'
result = deepcut.tokenize(thai)
```

Expected output:

```
[\['ตัดคำ','ได้','ดี','มาก'\]][1]
```

Tried:

```
for i in result:
  print(i.decode('utf-8'))

Error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: unexpected end of data

print([i for i in result])

Output: ['\xe0', '\xb8', '\x95', '\xe0', '\xb8', '\xb1', '\xe0', '\xb8', '\x94', '\xe0', '\xb8', '\x84', '\xe0', '\xb8', '\xb3', '\xe0', '\xb9', '\x84', '\xe0', '\xb8', '\x94', '\xe0', '\xb9', '\x89', '\xe0', '\xb8', '\x94', '\xe0', '\xb8', '\xb5', '\xe0', '\xb8', '\xa1', '\xe0', '\xb8', '\xb2', '\xe0', '\xb8', '\x81']
```

How can I get it to display the proper tokenized results or is there a better way to tokenize Thai language text?

Comment: On my machine it gives `['ตัด', 'คำ', 'ได้', 'ดี', 'มาก']` on print of result.  Your for loop gives error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` so provide steps to reproduce error

Comment: can you provide `print(result)`?

Comment: A [mcve] please.

Comment: @EmilyE. This is the exact example with errors except it runs on a Databricks notebook.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to convert it back to utf-8:

Just try:

```
import deepcut

thai = 'ตัดคำได้ดีมาก'
result = deepcut.tokenize(thai)

print([i for i in result])
```

output:

```
['ตัด', 'คำ', 'ได้', 'ดี', 'มาก']
```

Apart that you can also try this [Thai NLP Module](https://github.com/PyThaiNLP/pythainlp)

Comment: I tried printing the list without decoding but I am getting a bunch of ['\xe0', '\xb8', '\x95', ... as output. I am thinking it might be related to encoding errors to tokenize the thai text properly.

Comment: I get the same output with just `print(result)`